# Find exact substring in Rails activerecord searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

A contact has a string field of integers like `"1,10,14,5,15,2,5"`. 
For example I have 3 contacts:

`` contact1 has `"1,10,111,2,5"`
contact1 has `"10,14,5,15,2,5"`
contact1 has `"10,14,5"` ``

When I try to search for "1" it will return me contact1, when I search for 2 it will return me contact1 and contact2

What I have tried this code:

`contacts = Contact.all
contacts = contacts.where("tag_ids LIKE ?", "%#{tag}%")`

But in this code if I try to find out 1 it returns all 3 contacts.

Comment: All three include "1", so it is behaving exactly as you wrote it to behave!

Comment: I know! that's why I posted here so that I can change my existing query!

Comment: You should probably migrate your data field that contains your tag_ids as strings and create the relationship properly. Seems like you have a Tag model already, so all you need is an association table for contacts and tags and add the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. In your migration, just move all those IDs from that field into the association table before dropping it and you should have a lot easier way to find contacts based on tag IDs

Comment: Eventually I did what you mentioned. And it solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> `
>   contacts = contacts.where("tag_ids LIKE ?", **"#{tag}"**)

`